# How do i select mysql record and display in table multiple times based on certain columns?

Tags: mysql, database

i have a table like this:

```
id, name, date1, qty1, note1, date2, qty2, note2, date3, qty3, note3, admin
```

some example records:

```
1, something , 03-17-2017, 20, wow ,           ,   ,    ,           ,   ,     , greg
2, nothing   , 03-17-2017, 25, hmm , 03-18-2017, 26, ok ,           ,   ,     , dave
3, everything, 03-17-2017, 30, cool, 03-18-2017, 31, yup, 03-19-2017, 32, nice, john
```

so how would my select statement look like if i wanted to display data like this?

```
id | name       | date       | qty | note | admin
-------------------------------------------------
1  | something  | 03-17-2017 | 20  | wow  | greg
2  | nothing    | 03-17-2017 | 25  | hmm  | dave
2  | nothing    | 03-18-2017 | 26  | ok   | dave 
3  | everything | 03-17-2017 | 30  | cool | john
3  | everything | 03-18-2017 | 31  | yup  | john
3  | everything | 03-19-2017 | 32  | nice | john
```

so if there are no values for the #2 & #3 columns, then the records displays once.
if there are no values in the #3 columns, then the record displays twice.
if the #1, #2, and #3 columns have data, then the record displays as 3 rows.
when the record shows as 2 or more rows, each row should have some same values and some different values.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for jobs
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jobs`;
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `admin` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `note1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `qty1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `note2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `qty2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `note3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `qty3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of jobs
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `jobs` VALUES ('1', 'greg', 'something', '03-17-2017', 'wow', '20', '', '', '', '', '', '');
INSERT INTO `jobs` VALUES ('2', 'dave', 'nothing', '03-17-2017', 'hmm', '25', '03-18-2017', '26', 'ok', '', '', '');
INSERT INTO `jobs` VALUES ('3', 'john', 'everything', '03-17-2017', 'cool', '30', '03-18-2017', '31', 'yup', '03-19-2017', '32', 'nice');
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Seems like the table should be redesigned. Also doesn't seem to be PHP related. Store `thistable_id, qty, date, note` in another table. Then join the data.

Comment: please post the create from the table and the insert of the records then i will post you a query

Comment: put in create and insert records

Comment: edited typos in create section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a query like this, but in your post the create is not correct and i am nearly sure that the insert also changed the fields.

```
SELECT id, `name`, date1, qty,note,admin
FROM(

    SELECT id, 1 AS subid, `NAME`, date1 AS date1 , qty1 AS qty, note1 AS note , admin FROM jobs
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 2 AS subid, `name`, date2 AS date1 , qty2 AS qty, note2 AS note , admin FROM jobs WHERE date2 <>''
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 3 AS subid, `name`, date3 AS date1 , qty3 AS qty, note3 AS note , admin FROM jobs WHERE date3 <> ''

    ) AS tabs
ORDER BY id,subid;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to have multiple Primary Keys for the table.
Such as PRIMARY KEY(id, date)

```
CREATE TABLE notes (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name CHAR(30),
  date INT,
  qty INT,
  note CHAR(50),
  admin CHAR(10),
  PRIMARY KEY(id, date)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achive it by using [UNION ALL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)